# Abel-Dini-Type Theorem for convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given are a continuous, strictly increasing and convex function $\varphi:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ and a sequence $(x_j)$ of positive real numbers such that 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^\infty\varphi(x_j)
\end{align*}
converges.

> **Question:** Can we always find a sequence $(\lambda _j)$ of positive real numbers which decreases to 0 and so that
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=1}^\infty\varphi(x_j/\lambda_j)
> \end{align*}
>   still converges?

This is true for linear $\varphi$ by the Abel-Dini-Theorem, and in this case one can take $\lambda_j=\sqrt{x_{j+1}+x_{j+2}+\ldots}$. But what about the general case? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - here is a counterexample. Define

$$\phi(x)=\begin{cases}
0&x=0\\
\exp(-1/x)&0<x\leq 1/2\\
\exp(-2)+4\exp(-2)(x-\tfrac12)&x\geq 1/2.
\end{cases}$$

For $0<x<1/2$ we have $\phi'(x)=x^{-2}\exp(-1/x)$ and $\phi''(x)=(x^{-4}-2x^{-3})\exp(-1/x)>0$ which ensures that $\phi$ is continuous, strictly increasing and convex.

For $0<\lambda\leq 1$ and $0<y^\lambda<\exp(-2)$ we have

$$\phi(\tfrac1\lambda \phi^{-1}(x))=\phi(-1/\lambda\log(y))=y^\lambda.$$

For an extreme example take $x_j=\phi^{-1}(1/j(\log j)^2)$ for $j\geq 10$ (and $x_1,\dots,x_9=1$ say). Then

$$\sum_{j=10}^\infty \phi(x_j/\lambda)=\sum_{j=10}^\infty \frac{1}{j^\lambda(\log j)^{2\lambda}}$$

which converges for $\lambda=1$ but not for any $\lambda<1.$

Comment: Great, thank you!